# how does IntelliJ run .java files without compiling them?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I am new to Java but have learned that we cannot run a .java file directly. This is an annoyance coming from Python and Perl. But it seems like InteliJ does exactly that. If you run the program from within IntelliJ, the command that it shows at the top of the command window is something like this:

```
"C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_121\bin\java" "-javaagent:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\lib\idea_rt.jar=63733:C:\Program Files\JetBrains\IntelliJ IDEA Community Edition 2017.3.4\bin" -Dfile.encoding=UTF-8 -classpath "[epic classpath]" com.myorg.MyClass -programArg1 val1 -programArg2 val2
```

How does it do that, and how can I do something like that? I'm not opposed to compiling per se, I just don't want to juggle two files (the uncompiled version and the compiled version), or do two commands. I want to just run everything in one command.

Comment: It doesn't. It compiles them. Java is a compiled language-that's just the way it is. The command you show runs a compiled class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

See that `com.myorg.MyClass`?

That is the name of a **compiled** Java class. It is **not** referring to a java source code file!

IntelliJ is an **IDE**. It contains a compiler (actually, it can make use of the javac compiler, or the "eclipse" compiler that can continue to compile a class even after hitting an error in that class). It knows how to build stuff. That is the whole secret.

In other words: the Java source file is in fact compiled. The IDE does that for you without telling you.